# How to get the vector character inputs from checkboxGroupinput and convert in to a numeric score

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app that will calculate a score based on the user responses. It's important that I capture the user's input using the checkboxGroupInput. I understand that this function works by returning a vector of characters with the selected choices.

The choices for the checkboxGroupInput are the following: "CHF", "Hypertension", "Stroke / TIA / Thromboembolism history", "Vascular disease", "Diabetes"
Each choice gets a score After the user makes his/her choices I would like to return a total score value based on the choices. The score for each choice are the following "CHF" = 1 "Hypertension"= 1 "Stroke / TIA / Thromboembolism history"=2 "Vascular disease"=1 "Diabetes"=1

```
   checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "PMH", 
                         label = "Past Medical History",
                         choices =  c("CHF", "Hypertension", 
     "Stroke / TIA/Thromboembolism history", "Vascular disease", "Diabetes"))
```

I expect the output in shiny to be total score based on the choices the user makes.
Therefore I want to convert the character vector inputs to a total numeric score based on what the user chooses.
I think it comes down to 120 possible combinations
Some examples are the following:
If he/she made no choices the total score should be 0
If he/she chose all the choices the total score should be 6
if he/she chose "CHF" and "Stroke / TIA / Thromboembolism history" the total score should be 3
if he/she chose "CHF" and "Stroke / TIA / Thromboembolism history" and "Vascular Disease" score is 4
The output should be reactive so if user changes his choices to automatically recalculate the score

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make a named vector with the scores:

```
scores <- c(
  "CHF" = 1, 
  "Hypertension" = 1, 
  "Stroke / TIA/Thromboembolism history" = 2, 
  "Vascular disease" = 1, 
  "Diabetes" = 1
)
```

In `input$PMH` you have a vector containing some diseases, for example:

```
x <- c("CHF", "Vascular disease") # example of input$PMH
```

Then you get the total score like this:

```
sum(scores[x])
```